# How to get rid of 'Avoid using unnecessary statements' while using multiple statements in Ternary Operator

Tags: flutter, dart

This is what I wanna do:
check if the list contains 'something', if true => remove it => add 'anything' => print the list, else => add 'something' => print the list

```
List<String> components = List<String>();

ListTile(
 title: Text('Title'),
 onTap: () {
  components.contains('something')
   ? () {
      components.removeWhere((item) => item == 'something');
      components.add('anything');
     }
   : components.add('something');
  print(components);
 }
)
```

It runs just fine and the onTap function is working properly as it is supposed to but I get a blue curly underline around here:

```
? () {
```

It says 'Avoid using unnecessary statements.dart(unnecessary_statements)'. Is there a better approach on what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal function definition will look like this

```
myFunction(){
  ...
  ...
}
```

This is just a kind of declarations only.

To execute them you have to call it like `myFunction()` from somwhere.

Likewise definition of anonymous function will be like.

```
() { //without name
  ..
  ..
}
```

So to execute you need to add `()` at the end.

You only gave function definition after `?`. you have to call that function by adding `()` at the end

```
ListTile(
  title: Text('Title'),
  onTap: () {
    components.contains('something')
        ? () {
            components.removeWhere((item) => item == 'something');
            components.add('anything');
          }() //TODO: Make it as function call
        : components.add('something');
    print(components);
  },
)
```

Comment: This answers my question exactly right, thank you. But can you explain it more on why do I need to add (), it seems not right to me

Comment: @FederickJonathan I edited my answer. I am not native English & not good at explaining. hope you understand my explanation

Comment: Yea, I understand your edited answer now, thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

To keep your code readable and maintainable it would be better to do something like this:

```
ListTile(
    title: Text('Title'),
    onTap: _onTapTitle,
);

void _onTapTitle() {
  if (components.contains('something')) {
    components.removeWhere((item) => item == 'something');
    components.add('anything');
  } else {
    components.add('something');
  }
  print(components);
}
```

If you need to pass some data to the `_onTapTitle()` you could do this:

```
onTap: () => _onTapTitle(data),
```

Also, it might be better to move the `_onTapTitle()` logic to the bloc if you use BLoC pattern.

Comment: I will try to refactor it like that later. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, (There can be lots of way to this more efficiently)

```
  List<String> components = List<String>();

  void fun1(int index, dynamic otherData) {
      components.removeWhere((item) => item == 'something');
      components.add('anything');
      print('sflbknsfb');
  }

  void fun2 () {
      print('ssvskfjfsflbknsfb');

    components.add('something');
  }

ListTile(
    title: Text('Title'),

    // onTap: () {
    //   components.contains('something') ? fun1() : fun2();
    //   },

    //Or 

   onTap:() => components.contains('something') ? fun1() : fun2(),
 ),
```

Comment: The actual Widget Tree is a lot more complicated, the ListTile itself is in ListView.builder and the function needs the index from that but thanks for replying

Comment: So what is the complication? You can pass the index as argument to the function and can do whatever you want to do with index TIle of the Listview. Builder.

Comment: The ListView is a return value from a function called from a ShowModalBottom and some of the values are initialized in that. I will try to refactor it later as you suggested